# Geting value from key on javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have a JavaScript object that looks like what's shown in the image. There is a property called Fields which has several elements. Each element has a Key & Value property.

How do I get the value of a given element based on the key without iterating through the object's fields?

For example, I want to do something like comp.Fields["CountyName"] and get "Green, WI, USA" as the result. I don't want to do this (comp.Fields[5]) because the number position of the element might change in the future.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Comment: Your Fields looks like an array. If you want to do it the way above, you must make it it's own object. Also, you should avoid capitalizing variable names unless they are classes/constructors

Comment: Please post the actual code that you are working with in a minimal, executable fashion.

Answer (score 0):

You can access object elements and array elements in the same way, with square brackets. Just remember to just the correct key type.

alert(comp['Fields'][4]['Value']);

*Note the use of the integer 4 as the array key in Fields.*

Comment: How do I do this without using the integer 4? If the object is changed in the future, then the 4 might be incorrect. I would like to use they key value ("CountyName") instead.

Comment: That is to do with how you build the comp object, although comp is an object, comp['Fields'] is not. You have made Fields an array (comp['Fields'] = [];), not an object (comp['Fields'] = {};).

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer.

```
var obj = comp.Fields.filter(function (obj) {
   return obj.Key === 'CountyName';
})[0];
```